# Return value without numeric and punctuations

Tags: php, wordpress, screen-scraping, filtering, simple-html-dom

I'm trying to strip the numeric and punctuations from a string leaving only alpha characters in SIMPLE HTML DOM, with no success I've tried multiple approaches and just can't get it!

Example string: The Amazing Retard (2012) #1
Output string: The Amazing Retard

I understand it's for an undefined method and I've looked at multiple pages for this, however I'm brain farting for how to include the method. Any help would be appreciated. The error that I get is

Fatal error: Call to undefined method simple_html_dom_node::preg_replace() in /home/****/public_html/wp-content/themes/***/***.php on line 123

The code is as follows:

```
<?php

function scraping_comic()
{
    // create HTML DOM
    $html = file_get_html('http://page-to-scrape.com');

    // get block
    foreach($html->find('li.browse_result') as $article)
    {
        // get title
        $item['title'] = trim($article->find('h4', 0)->find('span',0)->outertext);
        // get title url
        $item['title_url'] = trim($article->find('h4', 0)->find('a.grid-hidden',0)->href);
        // get image
        $item['image_url'] = trim($article->find('img.main_thumb',0)->src);
        // get details
        $item['details'] = trim($article->find('p.browse_result_description_release', 0)->plaintext);
        // get sale info
        $item['on_sale'] = trim($article->find('.browse_comics_release_dates', 0)->plaintext);
        // strip numbers and punctuations
        $item['title2'] = trim($article->find('h4',0)->find('span',0)->preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z]/","",$item['title2'], 0)->plaintext);

        $ret[] = $item;

    }

    // clean up memory
    $html->clear();
    unset($html);

    return $ret;
}
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------


$ret = scraping_comic();

if ( ! empty($ret))
{
    $scrape = 'http://the-domain.com';


    foreach($ret as $v)
    {

        echo '<p>'.$v['title2'].'</p>';
        echo '<p><a href="'.$scrape.$v['title_url'].'">'.$v['title'].'</a></p>';
        echo '<p><img src="'.$v['image_url'].'"></p>';
        echo '<p>'.$v['details'].'</p>';
        echo '<p> '.$v['on_sale'].'</p>';
    }
}
else { echo 'Could not scrape site!'; }
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`preg_replace` is a php function, not a member of the `simple_html_dom_node` class. call it like this:

```
$matches = preg_replace ($pattern, $replacement, mixed $subject);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

it looks like your `$pattern` and `replacement` are OK; you'll just pass in as the `$subject` the input you're trying to change.

for example, this might be what you're trying to achieve:

```
$item['title2'] = 
  trim(preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z]/","",$article->find('h4',0)->find('span',0));
```

Comment: Not sure how it worked but I got it working using $matches = str_replace (' ', ' ', $article); and then changing strip numbers & punctuations to this: $item['title2'] = trim(preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z-\t\n\s]/","",$article->find('h4',0)->find('span',0)->plaintext)); using preg_replace would pump out empty warnings - replaced that with str_replace and the warnings went away

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because of this line :

```
// strip numbers and punctuations
    $item['title2'] = trim($article->find('h4',0)->find('span',0)->preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z]/","",$item['title2'], 0)->plaintext);
```

written like this it means that preg_replace is a method of your class simple_html_dom_node which is not as it's standard php function.

you might have in your class something like execute_php_function("a_php_function",anArrayOfArguments)

so you'll write something like this :

```
// strip numbers and punctuations
    $item['title2'] = trim($article->find('h4',0)->find('span',0)->execute_php_function("preg_replace",anArrayOfArguments)->plaintext);
```